# submitting form with ajax jquery

Tags: jquery

i have a form where i am storing the time spent by users on site so for every user there is one id and my form is

```
<form id="mycash" name="form6" method="post" action="">
<input name="Time_Spent1"  value="'.$row['Time_Spent'].'"  id="Time_Spent1"        type="text" size="7" readonly="readonly" /><input type="button" name="task" id="task" value="submit">
```

i am using this javascript to submit the form using ajax .but it is not working.

```
<script language="javascript">$(document).ready(function(){
$("form#mycash").submit(function() {
var Time_Spent1     = $(\'#Time_Spent1\').attr(\'value\');
var task     = $(\'#task\').attr(\'value\');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "page.tpl.php",
        data: "Time_Spent1="+ Time_Spent1 + "&\'{$client[\'id\']}\'="+ \'{$client[\'id\']}\'+ "&task="+ task,
        success: function(){
            $(\'form#mycash\').hide(function(){$(\'div.success\').fadeIn();});

        }
    });
return false;
});
```

});

i want to submit this form every 20 seconds automativcally . any suggestion where i am doing mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any automation. Try this:

```
(function submitForm(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("form#mycash").submit();
        submitForm();
    },20000);
}());
```

Comment: i have done it thanks but autosubmit is not working. Will you please check your autosubmit code . i think there is some error in code

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have '\ in jQuery selector
$(\'#Time_Spent1\') should be $('#Time_Spent1')., hope that will help.
The data part you should leave as JSON format

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "page.tpl.php",
    data: {"Time_Spent1":  Time_Spent1, "task" : task}
```

....

If you want to do automation submit, you should create a function and set interval to it

```
function submitform(){//Do something}

setInterval(submitform, 20000); //20k milisecond = 20secs
```